# Query muilt filed by date and ip in elasticesarch

Tags: elasticsearch

in elasticsearch data load from next josn data.
,i want  get the max value  of  cpu0 and in_eth1 for every ip  in elasticsearch and sorted by  date , so some one can help me with the flowing query?

```
{
  "ip":"10.235.13.172",
  "date":"2015-11-09",
  "time":"18:30:00",
  "cpu0":7"cpu13":2,
  "cpu14":1,
  "diskio(%)":0,
  "memuse(MB)":824,
  "in_eth1(Mbps)":34
}
     "aggs": {
         "events_by_date": {
            "date_histogram": {
               "field": "date",
               "interval": "day"
            },
           "aggs" : {
                   "genders" : {
                       "terms" : {
                           "field" : "ip",
                           "size": 100000,
                            "order" : { "_count" : "asc" }
                       },
                       "aggs" : {
                           "maxcpu" : { "max" : { "field" : "cpu(%)" } },
                           "maxin" : { "max" : { "field" : "in_eth1(Mbps)" } },
                       }
                   }
               }
         }
      }
```

Comment: Well, what's not working with this one? For me it seems just fine. Except some syntax errors.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas    thanks, i fixed the syntax errors, and then it worked